# porque display flex me arruina mi posicionamiento en el @media?

Tags: html, css, html5, flexbox

Mi pagina web tiene un conjunto de cartas que en computadora quiero que se vean 2 `row` de 3 cartas y una `row` mas de 1 carta , pero para celulares quiero que se vea como 3 `columns` una arriba de la otra, así viéndose como una gran `column` de 7 cartas.

El problema es que si pongo el `display:flex` en `.project-first-row` (en el `css` para computadora) luego no me deja en el `@media` poner `project-first-row{ flex-direction: column;}` **pero** solo en la primer columna, porque para `proyect-second-row` y para `proyect-second-row` **si** me deja.

Ahora, si le saco directamente el `display:flex` al `css` para computadora, si me deja poner `column` en el media, pero ya no se vería bien en la computadora (pero si en el celular). Espero que se entienda. Que puedo hacer?

```css
background-color:white;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 75px;
height: 45em;
text-align: center;

}
#project-text {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 380px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#project,
.project-line-one .project-line-two .project-line-three {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.project-first-row {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  /*este es el que luego en el media no me dejara cambiar a column el flex-direction, pero si se lo saco, si me deja en el media, pero ya no se ve bien en el css para computadora*/
}
.project123 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #d1d1e9;
}
.project123:hover {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #b172ff;
}
.project123 .portfolio-pic,
.generator-pic,
.match-pic {
  margin-left: -4px;
  max-width: 330px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.project-second-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.project456 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #d1d1e9;
}
.project456:hover {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #b172ff;
}
.project456 .expenses-pic,
.admin-pic {
  margin-left: -4px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.project456 .app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 35px;
  max-width: 290px;
  max-height: 290px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.project-third-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.project7 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-left: -841px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #d1d1e9;
}
.project7:hover {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #b172ff;
}
.project7 .movie-pic {
  margin-left: -4px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

/*CSS el @media estilandolo para un celular*/
height: fit-content;
width: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: red;

}
#project strong {
  margin-left:-21%;
}
#project-text {
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
project-first-row {
  flex-direction: column;
  /*esto no me lo toma por culpa del display:flex del css anterior, si se lo saco, ahi si me toma este, pero ya no se veria bien para computadoras*/
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
.project123 {
  width: 290px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 0.6%;
  background-color: orange;
}
.project123 .portfolio-pic,
.generator-pic,
.match-pic {
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-height: 285px;
}
.project-second-row {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.project456 {
  width: 290px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 0.6%;
}
.project456 .expenses-pic,
.admin-pic {
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-height: 285px;
}
.project-third-row {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: fit-content;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.project7 {
  width: 290px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 0.6%;
}
.project7 .movie-pic {
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 285px;
  max-height: 285px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project123">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/img portfolio icon.JPG" class="portfolio-pic">
    <span style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">Porfolio</span></a>
</div>
<div class="project123">
  <a href="https://gonzalezmariasol.github.io/website-in-progress/" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/memes-PICS.svg" class="generator-pic">
    <span style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">Meme Generator</span></a>
</div>
<div class="project123">
  <a href="https://gonzalezmariasol.github.io/website-in-progress/" target="_blank">
    <img src="img/match-PICS.svg" class="match-pic">
    <span style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">Match3</span></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="project-second-row">
  <div class="project456">
    <a href="https://gonzalezmariasol.github.io/website-in-progress/" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/money-PICS.svg" class="expenses-pic">
      <span style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">Expenses Tracking</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="project456">
    <a href="https://gonzalezmariasol.github.io/website-in-progress/" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/calendar-PICS.svg" class="admin-pic">
      <span style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">Meeting Planner</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="project456">
    <a href="https://gonzalezmariasol.github.io/website-in-progress/" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/app-PICS.svg" class="app">
      <span style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">All about Apps</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="project-third-row">
  <div class="project7">
    <a href="https://gonzalezmariasol.github.io/website-in-progress/" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/cine-PICS.svg" class="movie-pic">
      <span style="font-weight:bold; color: black;">Movie search</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero te sea de ayuda.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bandas{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(202, 191, 202);
    display:flex;
    border-radius: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 10px;
}

.card{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 300px;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .bandas{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .card{
        margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="bandas primary">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bandas secondary">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
    
        </div>
        <div class="bandas tertiary">
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```